# Dataitem selection undefined for multiple grids on the same page

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I am trying to double click, in onChange function, on the in progress grid to open a kendoWindow share on two grids on the same page but it does not open. When looking at the console, it gives error below relating to my inprogress grid, however, i can see data items in the actual grid. How should I go about to fix?

> Uncaught TypeError: dataItem is undefined

**Declaration**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getdata(que = 0);       
    $('#subform').hide(); $('#upd').hide();    
    getdata(que = 1);                                                                                     
 });
```

**GetData function**

```
function getdata(que) { 
        //console.log('que is:',que); 
        if(que==0){ 
             //   console.log('your in queue 0');                                            
            var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "triage_inv/get?id=0",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },                                
                    sort: { field: "open_dt_tm", dir: "asc"},
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return {
                                models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                            };
                        }
                    }
                },                                                                                    
                pageSize: 20,
                page: 1
            });

        }else if(que==1){ 
            //console.log('your in queue 1');                                            
                var remoteDataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "triage_inv/get?id=1",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },                                
                        sort: { field: "open_dt_tm", dir: "asc"},
                        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                return {
                                    models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    },                                                                
                    pageSize: 20,
                    page: 1
                }); 
            
        }
```

**InProgress grid object**

```
 $('#inprogress').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: remoteDataSource,
    height: 300,
    editable: "popup",
    change: onChange,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,                            
    selectable: true,                            
    toolbar: ["excel"],                                      
    excel: {
...
```

**Backlog grid object**

```
$('#backlog').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: remoteDataSource1,
    height: 400,
    editable: "popup",
    change: onChanger,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,                            
    selectable: true,                            
    toolbar: ["excel"],                                      
    excel: {
```

**onChanger function**

```
 function onChanger(e) {
    var rows1 = e.sender.select();                            
    rows1.each(function (e) {  
        var grid1 = $("#backlog").data("kendoGrid");
        grid1.tbody.find("tr").unbind().dblclick(function(e) {                                      
            var dataItem1 = grid1.dataItem(this);                                                                      
          //getsimilarscripts(searchData);
          var sr_num1 = dataItem1.ticket_number;
          myWindow.data("kendoWindow").open();
```

**onChange function**

```
function onChange(e) {
    var rows = e.sender.select();                                
    rows.each(function (e) {            
        var grid = $("#inprogress").data("kendoGrid");                                
        // Double click to retrieve ticket detail
        grid.tbody.find("tr").unbind().dblclick(function(e) {                                       
            console.log('inprogress grid >',grid.currentRow().dataItem(this));
          var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);                                                                     
          //getsimilarscripts(searchData);
          var sr_num = dataItem.ticket_number;
          myWindow.data("kendoWindow").open();
```

Comment: @Tofu did you have any suggestions for getting the inprogress grid to allow the doubleclick to work for the KendoWindow instead of the dataItem undefined?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, javascript is none of my I'm-good-at-it-languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the following if/else if conditions and it is working like a champ.

```
...
 if(que==0){  
...
}else if(que==1){
```